# What is a good choice for managing users/security in an SAAS environment?

Tags: java, security, rest

I'm building an SAAS application and looking for solutions to secure my RESTful API (written in Java/Jersey 2). Developers should be able to consume my REST API via an Access token.

I had a look at kong - but I'm honestly a bit worried about the deep integration. If kong will somehow not fit later anymore, it's hard to migrate to another security / API Layer management concept.

What are you thinking about node-oauth2?

Are there any good alternatives?

Also - is there any other way to securely generate an non-expiring Access token without Oauth2?